# Htaccess multiple redirects not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

We have a new domain name and want to redirect our old customers.
Now we have a small change we are changing from a nl domain to com, so we want our nl customers to go to the .com/nl and the English customers from /us/ to .com
It needs to be a 301 redirect and send the URL.
So we got this now, but it's not working

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^olddomain\.nl/ca$ /newdomain.com/ca/? [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^ olddomain\.nl/dk$ /newdomain.com/dk/? [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^ olddomain\.nl/us$ /newdomain.com/? [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^ olddomain\.nl$ /newdomain.com/nl? [L,R=301]
```

Wat are we doing wrong I'm in panic because we need to go live tomorrow. Hope somebody can help me

Ok so we got a bit furter.

```
RewriteEngine on
#olddomain/us =>newdomain/
RewriteRule ^us/?$ http://newdomain.com/ [NE,L,R]
#olddomain.nl/ =>newdomain/nl
RewriteRule ^$ http://newdomain.com/nl/ [NE,L,R]
#olddomain/others =>newdomain/others
RewriteRule ^(ca|dk)/ http://newdomain.com/$1 [NE,L,R=301]
```

**Not working**

1. olddomain.nl to newdomain.com/nl/
2. sending the old URL to the new    pagina like keep
   olddomain.nl/oldpage.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following rule in olddomain/.htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine on
#1)olddomain/us =>newdomain/
RewriteRule ^us/?(.*)?$ http://newdomain.com/$1 [NE,L,R]
#2)olddomain/others =>newdomain/others
RewriteRule ^(ca|dk)(/.*)?$ http://newdomain.com/$1$2 [NE,L,R=301]
#3)olddomain.nl/page =>newdomain/nl/page
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newdomain.com/nl/$1 [NE,L,R]
```

Comment: Thanks almost solved it, The only problem is left if i go to olddomain.nl it doesn't go to newdomain.com/nl/ also if i go to olddomain.nl/ca/testfolder it says 404 not found instead of redirect

Comment: Still not working fully I'm glad you are helping me out.
olddomain.nl goes to newdomain.com not ok should be newdomain.com/nl/
oldomain.nl/us/ goes to newdomain.com good
oldomain.nl/us/test123 goes to  newdomain.com almost ok /test123 is missing

Comment: @wesley sorry , I didnt notice that. There was a slight typo. please clear your browser cache and try the updated version now.

Comment: It's almost working with the dk and ca it's fully working redirect to nl also but on first two there is everything else missing like this olddomain.nl/testpage.php or olddomain.nl/us/page/ it should send it to the new domain like this newdomain.com/nl/testpage.php newdomain.com/page/

Comment: @Wesley try the new edit. I put the nl rule at 3rd position to avoid overriting of rules.

Comment: First rule almost works. Olddomain.nl/us/123 goes to newdomain.com//123 olddomain.nl does nothing just loads the page last rule fully works

Comment: @Wesley sorry sorry, a small typo. It is because of the pattern **(.+)** it doesnt match hompage . I changed it to **(.*)** . It should work now.

Comment: All working only 1 small thing do you know how to fix the // on the first rule?

Comment: @Wesley double leading slshes were added because of an additional / in the pattern. I have fixed that.